# A gateway between a router and PC to control the address space

Tags: networking, router, lan

I have a simple setup. A home router from the ISP and computer(s) connected to it. The issue is that the address space of the ISP router is quite unpredictable (sometimes my address may be in the 192.168.. range, other times it could be 10...*). This causes problems when I connect with the VPN where the address space conflicts with my LAN address space. I cannot modify my router's settings, because it is not mine, I'm just renting the place.

I thought of some device like a NAT (I'm not an expert, so I might be wrong here). I would put this device between the ISP router and my PC(s). My PC(s) would get local IP addresses from this new device in an address space that I'd control via some web interface of that device. All the traffic would go through that new device, which would in turn communicate with the original router to access Internet.

What should I buy? Would that new device be just a normal router? What kind of router?

Comment: If you do insert a NAT layer between your ISP router and your PC then you just bump the problem up a level. In order to connect to "public" IP of that NAT device you still need to know the IP it has been assigned by the ISP router. You need to solve whatever is going on with that IP address range of the ISP router.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What should I buy? Would that new device be just a normal router? What kind of router?

Yeah, it's just a router with DHCP and NAT (address masquerading) functions, i.e. literally a generic home wifi router.

Such a router could also be built from a Linux system with iptables or nftables, or BSD with pf.

> The issue is that the address space of the ISP router is quite unpredictable (sometimes my address may be in the 192.168.. range, other times it could be 10...*).

That's a bit unusual. (Not technically impossible, but "why *would* they do that?" kind of unusual.)

It sounds as if you might be talking to two different DHCP servers at once – e.g. you might sometimes receive an address from the ISP router, but sometimes from something else (such as a misconfigured wifi router that you meant to set up as an access point but forgot to turn DHCP off).

Or it could be that the ISP router itself is in bridge mode while still serving its own DHCP, so sometimes you get an IP address from your local ISP router, but sometimes from the ISP directly.

Comment: 192.168.*.* and 10.* are both common IP address ranges for local networks. You would never get an IP starting with that from the ISP because every ISP knows not to use the private ranges for public IP addresses. (They're reserved)

Comment: @Romen: That assumes ISPs always issue public IP addresses in the first place – which unfortunately hasn't been true for ages. Lots of residential ISPs have started implementing CGNAT recently (mostly but _not always_ using private RFC6598 space), but issuing private addresses and doing ISP-level NAT has already been the norm for many 3G/4G operators for years, not to mention campus/apartment internet connections (which are technically LANs but still act just like an ISP from a tenant's PoV).

Comment: If that is the kind of ISP that OP has, then they would be using the Class A address range and never the Class C range? If the ISP ethernet line is plugged in to the switch side then maybe the router's DHCP server is fighting with the ISP's DHCP server.

Comment: Correction to what I said above for correctness then. Major (Tier 1,2,3) ISPs are not supposed to use private ranges because they are peers with each other on one big network. If your ISP is using GCNAT that would mean they have no peers and one upstream provider, so they wouldn't cause issues by using NAT and a private address range for their customers.

Comment: @Romen: Using CGNAT doesn't prevent an ISP from having multiple upstreams. Their peers would never see packets with customers' private addresses – they'd only see packets that have already gone through the NAT system. (I mean that's literally *the job* of NAT.) If it prevents the first upstream from seeing the ISP's internal addressing, it'll do exactly the same with all other upstreams and/or peers.

Comment: Thanks for your input. Then, it seems to me that I should be looking at the xDLS type of routers, because they seem to have an Ethernet WAN socket (so I could connect that new router to the ISP-provided one).
Yeah, I could use something like a Raspberry Pi probably, but I want to have a few Ethernet sockets there + wi-fi, it'll be easier to just have a typical router.

Comment: @mnj: I think you want the opposite... Probably all home routers have an Ethernet port for WAN connection, but "xDSL" might actually be the exception to that – as it literally means that the router is also a DSL modem, using the DSL port for its primary WAN connection, so it _might_ be lacking an Ethernet WAN port, or sometimes have a switchable "LAN/WAN" port. (And even if it has one, you're still paying extra for the whole 'DSL modem' part that you don't need.) So look for a "generic" home wi-fi router instead. (Add an Ethernet switch if you want more ports.)

Comment: @user1686 I am thinking about getting this one: https://www.tp-link.com/en/home-networking/wifi-router/archer-c54/ It costs around 20 euro where I live.